# Lua returns "string" to C++ instead of "double" using lua_type(lua_state, lua_gettop(lua_state), what can be the problem?

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to call the function from `lua` repeatedly which returns a value to C++. I get type `double` most of the time, but sometimes it sends the same `double` value as `string`. For example=> 30.5 as "30.5".

Why is `lua` interpreting it a wrong way?

I have tried to return value from `lua` using `tonumber(return_value)`, to force it to number but it still gives me `string` sometimes.

for `lua` side:

```
function getValue()

mValue = 30+ 0.5  
return mValue

end

function init()

    print(" [lua]  Calling getValue")
    ret1 = getValue()
    return ret1  -- tried tonumber(ret1) also

end
```

for C++ side:

```
while (lua_gettop(lua_state) >= 1)

{

                str_buf.str(std::string());
        str_buf << " ";
    switch (lua_type(lua_state, lua_gettop(lua_state)))
    {
    case LUA_TNUMBER:
        {
            str_buf << "script returned the number: "
                << lua_tonumber(lua_state, lua_gettop(lua_state));
        }
        break;
    case LUA_TTABLE:
       str_buf << "script returned a table";
    break;
    case LUA_TSTRING:
        {
            std::string temp = lua_tostring(lua_state, lua_gettop(lua_state));
            str_buf << "script returned the string: "
                << temp;
        }
        break;
    case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
        {   
            str_buf << "script returned the boolean: "
            << lua_toboolean(lua_state, lua_gettop(lua_state));
        }
        break;
        default:
    str_buf << "script returned an unknown-type value";     
}
```

I always expect to get 30.5 in C++ and `case LUA_TNUMBER:` should be executed every time, but it goes to case `LUA_TSTRING:` sometimes.

Comment: Only *sometimes*? And there's no changes in the code (C++ or Lua)? Is there a pattern for this "sometimes"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually it keeps on running and i have set breakpoint inside LUA_TSTRING. Breakpoint is hit after sometime. And it changes every time I execute code without changing C++ or lua side.

Comment: Do you print it somewhere in Lua, concatenating it with message text?

Comment: Behavior that changes from run to run without any code changes, that smells like [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to me.

Comment: Does some part of you programming environment look at the Lua API stack SOMETIMES and invoke `lua_tolstring` or `lua_tostring` (for example, to display the content of the stack for debugging/logging/etc)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff not really.

Comment: @all thanks for your suggestions. I wasn't able to find reason for it but I handled it by using lua_tonumber, so i force any return type to number. As for my application, I know in advance what to expect as return value so i used it to force conversion of any type from lua to LUA_TNUMBER.